# jquery css opacity cross browser performance

Tags: jquery, css, performance, cross-browser, opacity

i need to change the opacity of DIVs (possibly containing images if it makes difference). Normally one would use

```
$('#id1').css('opacity', opacity1);
$('#id2').css('opacity', opacity2);
...
$('#idN').css('opacity', opacityN);
```

BUT if i have a lot of DIVs performance is dropping down a lot, especially in IE.
So my question is how to increase the performance? (cross browser solution, using jQuery is optional)

PS: opacity1,opacity2 and so on are always different and generated at the beginning of the script. And in fact they are changing with time... So it could be difficult to use classes, right? All DIVs are already cached (not shown here), so the only performance limiting step is css.opacity. For certain reasons i cant reattach parent elements as suggested by Kevin

Comment: Maybe use classes that are set on multiple DIVs rather than individual IDs each time.

Comment: You could try CSS transitions, and defiantly use classes on multiple DIVs rather than ids, as Billy Moat suggested.

Comment: What are these mystery elements? are they all siblings? Depending on the situation, you may be able to detach their parent element, do your css changes, then reattach the parent element resulting in just 2 redraws rather than one for each element you change.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand I think it can be done by css, and replace IDs by `jQuery` if required.
You just have to use filter for IE browsers as below.

```
#id1 {opacity:0.4; filter:alpha(opacity=40);}
#id2 {opacity:0.6; filter:alpha(opacity=60);}
#id3 {opacity:0.8; filter:alpha(opacity=80);}
```